# ServiceController.WaitForStatus with multiple desiredStatus

Tags: c#, service, windows-services

I currently use the following to wait until the service is started...

```
srvCtl.Start();
srvCtl.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30))
```

In case somehow the service was stopped immediately after it was started I also want to account for it being stopped.

Is there a way to wait for both `ServiceControllerStatus.Running` and `ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped`

Answer (score 1):

The following could be a bit problematic as tasks and threads don't like each other very much, but you could do:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokeSource();

List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>
{
    Task.Run(()= > srvCtl.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30)), cts),
    Task.Run(()= > srvCtl.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30)), cts),
    ...
}

// When any of the tasks completes, it means the service reached on of the statuses you were tracking
await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

// To cancel the rest of the tasks that are still waiting
cts.Cancel();
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

WaitforStatus throws a timeout exception if the timespan expires before starting.

You can check the current and desired state in the exception handler and do whatever you think is appropriate there. If you set a small enough timeout, you can test, then exit or retry as appropriate.

I don't believe WaitforStatus supports multiple simultaneous conditions, but letting it expire, then checking seems to be pretty close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `ServiceController.WaitForStatus` does nothing but check every 0.25 s if the service is in the desired state. (Source: decompilation of the .NET Framework code.) It follows that if you try to wait for a transient state, you may miss it. So it's an overkill to create multiple tasks (and threads) to wait for each one of the states; just reproduce the actual .NET code and change the return condition.

```
    public static ServiceControllerStatus WaitForStates(this ServiceController service, TimeSpan timeout, params ServiceControllerStatus[] states)
    {
        //parameter checks omitted

        DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;

        while (true)
        {
            service.Refresh();

            ServiceControllerStatus currentState = service.Status;
            if (states.Contains(currentState))
                return currentState;

            TimeSpan elapsedTime = DateTime.UtcNow - start;
            if (elapsedTime > timeout)
                throw new TimeoutException();

            Thread.Sleep(250);
        }
    }
```